# How to find element by long complicated xpath?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to find a button, but don't know how as the html code is complicated. Can you help me?

HTML

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <span style="display: inline-block; margin: 5px; padding: 10px 15px; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 16px; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(99, 99, 102);">Bugsnag akzeptieren
  </span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; margin: 5px; padding: 10px 15px; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 18px; line-height: 16px; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(0, 122, 255);">Alle akzeptieren
  </span>
</div>
```

So I want to find the second element and tried things like:

```
self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@style='the whole text that equals style in the html']")
```

But it does not seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you would like to do with it, you could do `//span[2]` to select the second span:

Example of Selecting Element

`self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[2]")`
[image]

if you want the entire element.

---

Example of Selecting Text

`self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[2]/text()")`

if you want the inner html text of the second span.

I tested the xpath expression on this [website](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) to make sure that it works.

I copied in the html you provided and just entered the xpath expression `//span[2]/text()` to test it.
[image]

More info on xpath [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

Comment: Thanks, but now there is an error, when I try it: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//span[2]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141). The website I am trying to login is https://homeworker.li/auth. There a pop-up is shown, and I have to click it away.

Comment: Oh, that was just an example of selecting the text, but to get the entire element itself just use `//span[2]` with nothing after it. Sorry it was not clear in the first post, also I made a mistake a put a slash, I'll edit the post.

Comment: Oh man it works! Thanks! But for some weird reason the object is in a list: I had to click the lists first element. Sorry for that nooby reply